# What does it mean to call horizontal lines through O the "points at infinity" in real projective plane $RP^2$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

[image]

This is a picture from my book. I extended the line M to get a better idea of where $p_n$ is.

It says the following:

It is natural to call the horizontal lines through O the "points at infinity".

What exactly does this mean?

If the points are on the z=-1 plane, how can line m extend to horizontal lines through the origin? I'm assuming horizontal lines through the origin means the xaxis, yaxis, or any lines in the plane z=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the horizontal lines do refer to the lines on z=0, they are called points at infinity as each line is represented by the point at which it intersects z=-1 plane but since lines laying on z=0 never intersect z=-1 they are said to intersect it at 'infinity'.

Comment: So does that mean if the eye at origin looks far enough, it will see the lines L approach z=0?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by far enough, but the lines L pass through the origin and hence diverge away from z=0. But points on z=-1 farther away from the origin correspond to lines which make smaller angles with the z=0 plane and hence as we go to infinity the lines become closer (smaller angle) to z=0